# fleet route trip calculation algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, tracking

I am trying to come up with an algorithm for calculating total trips but a vehicle I work for a transport company they have 5 depot distributed across the country well um currently developing a reporting module calculates the total trips of a vehicle.
this what constitutes a complete trip

1. 1 depot A to loading point to off-loading back to depot A (that's one
   trip)
2. 2 depot A to loading point to off-loading loading point to
   off-loading back to depot A (that's 2 in one trip)
3. 3 depot A to loading point to off-loading back to depot B (that's
   one    trip)
4. 4 depot A to loading point to off-loading back to depot B loading
   point    to off-loading to depot C (that's 2 trip)

the movement of the vehicle is stored in the database stored with its repective longituted and latitude here is the algorithm that i have came up with

the longitude and latitude of the depots is stored in the database.
Here is code below of how I tried to tackle it the code below is implemented in C#

```
  Telerik.Windows.Controls.Map.Location currentLocation;
               Telerik.Windows.Controls.Map.Location previousLocation = new Telerik.Windows.Controls.Map.Location() ;
               long loopCounter = 0;
               decimal distance = 0;
               int tripcounter = 0;
               bool isInTrip = false;
                     while (dr.Read())
               {
                   // get current location
                   currentLocation = new Telerik.Windows.Controls.Map.Location()
                   {
                       Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(dr[0]),
                       Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(dr[1])
                   };
                   //asign the current position to previous postion on first iteration
                   if (loopCounter == 0)
                   {
                       previousLocation = currentLocation;
                       loopCounter++;
                       continue;
                   }
                   //check whether the current and previous position fall within any of the starting/loading zones
                   Tuple<bool, bool> posVals = VehicleIsInStartingPoint(currentLocation, previousLocation);
                   //check if the previous postion was starting zone
                   if (posVals.Item2)
                   {
                       //check if the current postion is not a starting zone then this qualifies as trip
                       if (!posVals.Item1)
                       {
                           isInTrip = true;
                       }
                   } 
                   if (isInTrip)
                   {
                       tripcounter++;
                   }
                   isInTrip = false;
                   previousLocation = currentLocation;
               }
               tripcounter = tripcounter / 2;
               return tripcounter;
```

the above code executes inside a loop it get the the position of the current record which from the database creates a loaction object, check to see if its the first time its entered the loop. the location object is then stored to 2 reference objects one being the current position (representing the current record of iteration) and the other which previousLocation (representing the previous record iteration). The VehicleIsInStartingPoint
 method takes in two arguments both of them being type loaction the first one representing the current location and second on representing the previous location the methos loops through the gps coordinates of the depot and check whether if it falls within the radius of the gps coordinates of the depot. if falls within the radius it records true for item1 of the Tuple (item1 representing Current position) the same applies for the previous position
the boolean variable isInTrip is used to determine whether the trip counter should be increamented. 
To that it first checks whether if the previous location was within the radius of the depots if that if test passes it check whether the current position is not within the range of the depot, if so it set the variable isInTrip  to true, then w e check whether the variable isInTrip is true so that we may increment the tripcounter variable.
which at the the end of loop i then divide the tripcounter variable by 2 since a trip constitues from depot to loading and offloading zone and back to depot however when testing the module in working environment my module add one trip more compared to actual figures.

Can help me improve on algorithm or in my code it make it more accurate please

Thanks in advance

Comment: Punctuation! Useful, it is.

Comment: don't see how/where you are declaring `previousLocation`, you might want to set it by declaring a new object for `previousLocation` when setting `previousLocation = currentLocation`